# Using modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> - When the number $357a$ is divided by $5$, the remainder is $2$
>
> Evaluate the values $a$ can take.

I'm aware of the fact that we could just take a look into divisibility rule of $5$, which yields $a \in  \{0,5\}$. Since the remainder is $2$, we get that $a \in  \{2,7\}$. What about using modular arithmetics?

$$3000 + 500 + 70 + a \equiv 2 \pmod {5}$$

After simplification

$$ a \equiv 2 \pmod {5}$$

I don't know whether it is correct. Can you assist?

Regards

Comment: Is it correct to read $357a$ as a four digit number and not $357 \times a$?

Comment: I think it's supposed to be $3000+500+70+a$, not ${}+700+{}$. Not that it matters modulo $5$.

Comment: @MRobinson Yes, it is.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry for typo.

Comment: @Busi Then yes, what you've written is totally correct

Comment: You've written the right things, and the answer is correct.

Comment: Solve $357 \cdot a \equiv 2\mod 5$.

Comment: you should write $\overline{357a}$ or state "four digit number $357a$" to be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm, your answer is completely  correct, and must have resulted from the fact that $3000,500$ and $70$ are divisible by $5$, so these terms vanish from the left hand side, leaving $a \equiv 2 \mod 5$.

Another equivalent way of solving this problem, is that instead of breaking into powers of $10$ (digit expansion), you simply note that $357a - a = 3570 = 5 \times (2 \times 357)$ is a multiple of $5$, so by the definition of congruence, $357a \equiv a \mod 5$  directly follows , so $a \equiv 2 \mod 5$, and $a$ is a single digit number so we can conclude.

Comment: Why is that $a \equiv 5 \mod 2$?

Comment: Typo. I must correct it.